# Знак минуса в "Смене репутации" (change reputation)

Tags: поддержка

Что значит знак  - (минус) в "смене репутации"(change reputation)? У меня стоит  - 5. Это те очки, которые снимают с меня, когда минусуют мой ответ?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смена в -5 больше похожа на отмен голоса "за", чем на голос "против". Возможно, что кто-то проголосовал за Ваш вопрос (это даёт +5), а потом передумал. Голос "против" вычитает 2 очка.

Советую ознакомиться:

- [Справка по репутации](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)
- [Подробный отчёт о ней, для конкретного пользователя](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation)